# Accessing jsonpath elements with nested objects

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am looking to extract certain values from a JSON path of arrays and objects and use these values for further processing and am struggling with accessing those elements. Here is the JSON response:

```
[  
 {  
  "od_pair":"7015400:8727100",
  "buckets":[  
     {  
        "bucket":"C00",
        "original":2,
        "available":2
     },
     {  
        "bucket":"A01",
        "original":76,
        "available":0
     },
     {  
        "bucket":"B01",
        "original":672,
        "available":480
     }
    ]
    },
 {  
  "od_pair":"7015400:8814001",
  "buckets":[  
     {  
        "bucket":"C00",
        "original":2,
        "available":2
     },
     {  
        "bucket":"A01",
        "original":40,
        "available":40
     },
     {  
        "bucket":"B01",
        "original":672,
        "available":672
     },
     {  
        "bucket":"B03",
        "original":632,
        "available":632
     },
     {  
        "bucket":"B05",
        "original":558,
        "available":558
     }
    ]
 }
]
```

I tried accessing the root elements with $ but I could not get further with it.

Here is the test method that I have written. I want to extract the value for od_pair and within each od_pair, I need to be able to retrieve the bucket codes and their available numbers.

```
public static void updateBuckets(String ServiceName, String DateOfJourney) throws Exception {
    File jsonExample = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "\\LogAvResponse\\LogAvResponse.json");
    JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(jsonExample);

    List<Object> LegList = jsonPath.getList("$");
    // List<HashMap<String, String>> jsonObjectsInArray = jsonPath.getList("$");

    int NoofLegs = LegList.size();
    System.out.println("No of legs :" + NoofLegs);
    for (int j = 0; j <= NoofLegs; j++)
    // for (HashMap<String, String> jsonObject : jsonObjectsInArray) {
    {

        String OD_Pair = jsonPath.param("j", j).getString("[j].od_pair");
        // String OD_Pair = jsonObject.get("od_pair");

        System.out.println("OD Pair: " + OD_Pair);
        List<Object> BucketsList = jsonPath.param("j", j).getList("[j].buckets");

        int NoOfBuckets = BucketsList.size();
        // System.out.println("OD Pair: " + OD_Pair);
        System.out.println("no of Buckets: " + NoOfBuckets);

        for (int i = 0; i < NoOfBuckets; i++) {
            String BucketCode = jsonPath.param("j", j).param("i", i).getString("[j].buckets[i].bucket");
            String Available = jsonPath.param("j", j).param("i", i).getString("[j].buckets[i].available");

            int BucketCodeColumn = XLUtils.getBucketCodeColumn(BucketCode);
            int ServiceRow = XLUtils.getServiceRow(ServiceName, DateOfJourney, OD_Pair);
            System.out.println("Row of " + ServiceName + ":" + DateOfJourney + "is:" + ServiceRow);
            System.out.println("Bucket Code column of " + BucketCode + " is: " + BucketCodeColumn);
            XLUtils.updateAvailability(ServiceRow, BucketCodeColumn, Available);
        }
    }

}
```

}

This is the error I see:

```
Caused by: 
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup 
failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: [ @ line 1, column 27.
restAssuredJsonRootObject.[j].od_pair
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: `I need to be able to retrieve the bucket codes and their available numbers.` Base on `od_pair`, right?

Comment: I want to be able to access not just the od_pair but also the bucket objects within. So each od_pair has many buckets as objects. With your solution of Hashmap, I am not sure how I can reach out to the various buckets within each od_pairs

Comment: Yes thats correct @Fenio

Comment: Okay, got it. There are a few solutions but I'll show you extended and the best (in my opinion) one. I need a few minutes

Comment: @Fenio: So basically I am trying to run nested for loops, one for getting the od_pair and within that a for loop for buckets to get each bucket code and available number. Apologies as I am a newbie and hence some of my questions may sound naive here.

Comment: Don't apologize for the questions. Just make sure people understand what you want to do and show the effort :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest parsing your JSON into Java classes to ease the processing.

How to do that?
First, we need to create Java classes which will represent the JSON you provided.

Let's analyze the JSON.
Starts with an array. The array contains multiple JSON Object. These objects contain `od_pair` value and array of objects called `buckets`.

Let's create a class (you can name it whatever you want) `Pair`

```
public class Pair {
    public String od_pair; //this name is important because it corresponds with the json element's name!
    public List<BucketObject> buckets; //same here!
}
```

This class represents a single JSON Object in the main Array. It contains `od_pair` value AND nested JSON Array but in Java representation -> List of `BucketObject` classes. Let's create `BucketObject` class:

```
public class BucketObject { //this name is NOT importnat
    public String bucket; //names are important
    public int original;
    public int available;
}
```

We have only 3 values in each of the objects.

Now, it's time to parse JSON into the written classes.

```
JsonPath path = JsonPath.from(json);
Pair[] pairs = path.getObject("$", Pair[].class);
```

Remember that `Pair` is a single JSON Object. That's why we start parsing from the root represented by dollar sign `$` and we declare that JSON should be parsed into an ARRAY of `Pair` objects!

Now, processing will be much simpler!

I am not sure what do you need, but I will show you an example of how to get data from the buckets based on `od_pair` field and you should be able to figure out the rest of the processing.

So, we have the array of Pair class: `Pair[] pairs`;

Now, we want to get 1 Pair object based on `od_pair` value.

```
    public static Pair getPairBasedOnOdPairValue(Pair[] pairs, String odPairValue) {
        for (Pair pair : pairs) {
            if (pair.od_pair.equals(odPairValue)) return pair;
        }

        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
```

Now, we have the `Pair` object. We can access `buckets` for this object using

```
List<BucketObject> buckets = pair.buckets;
```

The rest of the processing is iterating over `List<BucketObject>` and getting desired values.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much @Fenio, I shall implement this approach and update on how it goes.

Comment: @Mihir If you have more troubles - create another question. I scan questions tagged `rest assured` regularly :)

Comment: Ok sure will do @Fenio. Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. just for my understanding and learning, would you also be able to advice on the for loop code that I had written earlier. Where I had nested for loops one for getting the od_pair and one for getting bucket information please? What was I missing there or where was I going wrong? @Fenio

Comment: @Mihir I'll check tomorrow

Comment: @Mihir I added some explanations in the second answer. I can't just point out where you did wrong but hopefully, you will be able to fix it by yourself

Comment: Created a new question on this in - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57288085/accessing-objects-within-nested-loops-using-hashmap-list @Fenio

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57288085/accessing-objects-within-nested-loops-using-hashmap-list/57289543#57289543. I've added the solution too. Thanks for all your help :) @Fenio

Answer (score 1):

OP asked me to advise on how to fix his code, hence the second answer.

Let's analyze the code you provided:

```
public static void updateBuckets(String ServiceName, String DateOfJourney) throws Exception {
    File jsonExample = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "\\LogAvResponse\\LogAvResponse.json");
    JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(jsonExample);

    List<Object> LegList = jsonPath.getList("$");
    // List<HashMap<String, String>> jsonObjectsInArray = jsonPath.getList("$");

    int NoofLegs = LegList.size();
    System.out.println("No of legs :" + NoofLegs);
    for (int j = 0; j <= NoofLegs; j++)
    // for (HashMap<String, String> jsonObject : jsonObjectsInArray) {
    {

        String OD_Pair = jsonPath.param("j", j).getString("[j].od_pair");
        // String OD_Pair = jsonObject.get("od_pair");

        System.out.println("OD Pair: " + OD_Pair);
        List<Object> BucketsList = jsonPath.param("j", j).getList("[j].buckets");

        int NoOfBuckets = BucketsList.size();
        // System.out.println("OD Pair: " + OD_Pair);
        System.out.println("no of Buckets: " + NoOfBuckets);

        for (int i = 0; i < NoOfBuckets; i++) {
            String BucketCode = jsonPath.param("j", j).param("i", i).getString("[j].buckets[i].bucket");
            String Available = jsonPath.param("j", j).param("i", i).getString("[j].buckets[i].available");

            int BucketCodeColumn = XLUtils.getBucketCodeColumn(BucketCode);
            int ServiceRow = XLUtils.getServiceRow(ServiceName, DateOfJourney, OD_Pair);
            System.out.println("Row of " + ServiceName + ":" + DateOfJourney + "is:" + ServiceRow);
            System.out.println("Bucket Code column of " + BucketCode + " is: " + BucketCodeColumn);
            XLUtils.updateAvailability(ServiceRow, BucketCodeColumn, Available);
        }
    }

}
```

I am not using compilator right now, so I can miss a few things.

**#1**

First thing I can see is that you save the main array into the `List<Object>`
`List<Object> LegList = jsonPath.getList("$");`

Instead, you could save it to more understandable type, since Object is so generic, you have no idea what's inside it.

`List<HashMap<String, Object>> LegList = jsonPath.getList("$");`

**#2**
The `for` loop looks incorrect because of the evaluator 
`j <= NoofLegs;`. 
This will probably cause `IndexArrayOutOfBoundsException` or something similar. With the given code, if you have 4 legs, the `for` loop will try to process 5 legs which are incorrect.

**#3**
Similar to the #1, line where you save the bucket list 
`List<Object> BucketsList = jsonPath.param("j", j).getList("[j].buckets");`
Could also be changed to `List<HashMap<String, Object>>` instead.

If you'd do that, you wouldn't need integer-based nested `for` loop.

You see, the `HashMap<String, Object>` is actually crucial to parse nested objects. The String is just a name like `buckets` or `od_pair`. It's the JSON representation. The second argument `Object` is different. RestAssured returns different types within the HashMap, that's why we use `Object` instead of `String`. Sometimes it's not String.

Example based on your JSON:

Collect buckets to List of HashMaps:

`List<HashMap<String, Object>> bucketsList = jsonPath.param("j", j).getList("[j].buckets");`

Each of the HashMap in the list is a representation of this:

```
{  
        "bucket":"C00",
        "original":2,
        "available":2
},
```

The `Object` in `HashMap` is either `String` or `Integer` in your case.
So, if you get element `bucket` from a `HashMap` you'll get its value.

Let's combine it with `for` loop for further clarification:

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> bucketsList = jsonPath.param("j", j).getList("[j].buckets");
for (HashMap<String, Object> singleBucket : bucketsList) {
    String firstValue = (String) singleBucket.get("bucket");
    Integer secondValue = (Integer) singleBucket.get("original");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Your explanation is very clear and helps in understanding this so well. Thank you very much for your help Sir!

Comment: @Mihir You are very welcome :) Feel free to ask more questions if you need help

Comment: I loved this above approach you have provided. I just have one question on this. I've added a section below again. If you could kindly reply.@Fenio

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message, it looks like you are using [rest-assured](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured) and that the `JsonPath` class is `io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath` from the rest-assured library.

I'm sure you're aware, but (perhaps for other readers) note that this is different from [Jayway's json-path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) and is NOT the `com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath` class from that library.

Also be aware that, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#json-using-jsonpath) rest-assured uses the [Groovy GPath](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath) syntax for manipulating/extracting JSON.

With that, I believe the following will extract what you need, i.e. od_pair and their corresponding buckets with available numbers:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> map = JsonPath.with(jsonString).get("collectEntries{entry -> [entry.od_pair, entry.buckets.collectEntries{bucketEntry -> [bucketEntry.bucket, bucketEntry.available]}]}");
```

where for each entry of the map, the key is the od_pair and the value is another map whose key is the bucket and value is the available number. The `jsonString` is the JSON you provided in the question.

You can iterate through the map to get what you want:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Integer>> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    String od_pair = entry.getKey();

    Map<String, Integer> bucketMap = entry.getValue();

    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> bucketEntry : bucketMap.entrySet())
    {
        String bucket = bucketEntry.getKey();
        int available = bucketEntry.getValue();
    }
}
```

Printing out the map you will get:

`{7015400:8727100={C00=2, A01=0, B01=480}, 7015400:8814001={C00=2, A01=40, B01=672, B03=632, B05=558}}`

Printing the map as JSON using Gson:

```
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(map));
```

you will get

```
{
  "7015400:8727100": {
    "C00": 2,
    "A01": 0,
    "B01": 480
  },
  "7015400:8814001": {
    "C00": 2,
    "A01": 40,
    "B01": 672,
    "B03": 632,
    "B05": 558
  }
}
```

For background, the String `collectEntries{entry -> [entry.od_pair, entry.buckets.collectEntries{bucketEntry -> [bucketEntry.bucket, bucketEntry.available]}]}`

is a Groovy closure that uses methods from the Groovy Collections API: Refer [Collection](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html), [List](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html) and [Map](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html)

Shout out to @Fenio for the pure Java solution above.