# Running RestAssured smoke tests with maven on different environments with its own unique API keys as headers

Tags: maven, rest-assured

I have a set of RestAssured tests marked as smoke tests and I am using maven to run them via command line using the command 
mvn test -PSmokeTests -Denv=QA

The env=QA is defined as a system property in pom.xml. I understand that If I need to run this on a different env like dev or staging or prod, I can specify that as a command line argument and within my tests, I can handle it.

However each of these environments need to use a different API key for that environment passed as a header in the API requests. I am storing the keys in a separate headers_key file and referencing them in the code. However I want to avoid this as I dont want the keys to be visible when I push my code into a source code repo like git.

Is there any efficient way of handling this within maven? Can the API keys be stored in such a way that they get picked up depending on the environment without having to store them in a separate file within the RestAssured framework?

Here is my pom.xml snippet:

```
    <profile>
        <id>SmokeTests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <env>${env}</env>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>SmokeTests.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        </profile>
```

And this is how I am currently handling it within the RestAssured code:

```
public static RequestSpecification getJSONRequestSpecification() {
    REQUESTBUILDER = new RequestSpecBuilder();
    env = System.getProperty("env");
    if (env.matches("QA")) {
        REQUESTBUILDER.setBaseUri(Path.BASE_URI_QA);
        REQUESTBUILDER.addHeader("X-Api-Key", APIKeys.QA_API_KEY);
    } 
    if (env.matches("Dev")) {
        REQUESTBUILDER.setBaseUri(Path.BASE_URI_Dev);
        REQUESTBUILDER.addHeader("X-Api-Key", APIKeys.Dev_API_KEY);
    } 
    if (env.matches("Staging")) {
        REQUESTBUILDER.setBaseUri(Path.BASE_URI_Staging);
        REQUESTBUILDER.addHeader("X-Api-Key", APIKeys.Staging_API_KEY);
    } 
    if (env.matches("Integration")) {
        REQUESTBUILDER.setBaseUri(Path.BASE_URI_Int);
        REQUESTBUILDER.addHeader("X-Api-Key", APIKeys.Int_API_KEY);
    } 
    REQUESTBUILDER.setContentType(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON);
    REQUEST_SPEC = REQUESTBUILDER.build();
    REQUEST_SPEC.log().ifValidationFails();
    return REQUEST_SPEC;
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just put API keys in profiles?

Comment: Want to avoid putting key information in any files that can be checked in source code repo. Is there a better way to manage this @Fenio?

Comment: You can always set environment variables on systems that run the automated tests and "drive" them with maven profile. That would exclude API keys from the source code

Comment: Thanks @Fenio. Will try that and keep you posted. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the api key using command line variables similar to how you are passing env.

```
mvn test -PSmokeTests -Denv=QA -DapiKey="keyvalue123"
```

You can ccess api key inside your java project using the following command

```
String apiKey = System.getProperty("apiKey");
```