# Setting invocationCount from a variable

Tags: testng, rest-assured

I have a test class with a test method that needs to run 'n' number of times. The number n is got from a API response. I tried passing 'n' into the invocationCount of the test method but it says invocationCount can only accept a constant value and not from a variable.

I tried to go through IAnnotationTransformers documentation but I wasn't able to understand what exactly I need to change in my tests to implement it.

Here is the code

```
public class JourneySearch1PaxTest  {

.....


@BeforeClass
public void setup() {
    reqSpec = RestUtilities.getRequestSpecification();
    authtoken = RestUtilities.createAuthToken();
    // System.out.println("Auth_Token is " +authtoken);
    reqSpec.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + authtoken);
    reqSpec.basePath(Path.V2_APIS);
    resSpec = RestUtilities.getResponseSpecification();


}

...few methods.....

@Test   
  public void GetNumbers() throws Exception {

   Response response=
   given()
   //.log().all()
  .spec(reqSpec)
  .pathParams("service_name", ServiceName, "travel_date", TravelDate, "origin", Origin, "destination", Destination)
   .when()
   .get(EndPoints.SERVICE_DETAILS)
   .then()
   .log().all()
   .spec(resSpec)
   .extract().response()             
        JsonPath jsPath = RestUtilities.getJsonPath(response);
    BBucket = jsPath.getString("data.inventory_details[1].remaining_capacity");
        System.out.println("BBucketCapacity:" +BBucket);
    BBucketTBL=(Integer.parseInt(BBucket)*Integer.parseInt(LoadCapacity)/100);
        System.out.println("BBucketCapacityTBL:" +BBucketTBL);


 }

  @Test(invocationCount = BBucketTBL)
  public void CreateBookings() throws IOException {

    JSONObject jObject = PrepareJourneySearchRequestBody(Origin,Destination,TravelDate);

    Response response = 
    given()
    //.log().all()
    .spec(reqSpec)
    .body(jObject.toString())
    .when()
    .post(EndPoints.JOURNEY_SEARCH)
    .then()
    .spec(resSpec)
    .extract().response();

    JsonPath jsPath = RestUtilities.getJsonPath(response);
    TariffCode = GetTariffCode(jsPath);


    System.out.println("TariffCode = " +TariffCode);


    JSONObject BookingObject = PrepareProvBookingRequestBody(Origin,Destination,TravelDate,ServiceName,TariffCode);
     Response Bookingresponse=
               given()
               //.log().body()
                .spec(reqSpec)
                .body(BookingObject.toString())
                .when()
                .post(EndPoints.BOOKING)
                .then()
                .spec(resSpec)
                //.log().body()
                .extract().response();
               JsonPath jsP = RestUtilities.getJsonPath(Bookingresponse);
               BookingNumber = jsP.get("data.booking.booking_number");
               float TotalPrice=jsP.get("data.booking.total_price");
               System.out.println("Booking number from create: " + BookingNumber);
               System.out.println("Price from create: " + TotalPrice);

}

}
```

Can someone kindly help me understand how can I get the invocationCount on the CreateBookings() test method to accept the value of BBucketTBL value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to crack this! The variable that I wanted to be considered for the invocation count is now stored in an external file and in my transformer class, I have method that reads that number first and uses that as a parameter when I set the invocation count.

Here is the transformer class code:

```
public class MyTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

  public int getbucketno() throws IOException {

  FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Misc\\BucketNumber");
  String line;
  String bucketno;
  int bucketnum=0;
  int i=0;
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

  while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
 {
    if (line.contains("BBucketTBL")) {
        bucketno = line.split(":")[1].trim();
        bucketnum=Integer.parseInt(bucketno);
        break;
    }
}
return bucketnum;
}

 //public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod, int i) {


 public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
    {
        int i = 0;
        try {
            i= getbucketno();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // int n = JourneySearch1PaxTest.class.getField(name)
        if ("CreateBookings".equals(testMethod.getName())) {
            //int i =0;
            ((ITestAnnotation) annotation).setInvocationCount(i);
        }
    }

}

}
```

The BucketNumber file has something like:

```
 BBucketTBL:25
```

The test method runs 25 times exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do partially achieve this by using IAnnotationTransformer using some self learning.

I created a separate class file with the following:

```
public class MyTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
    {
        // int n = JourneySearch1PaxTest.class.getField(name)
        if ("CreateBookings".equals(testMethod.getName())) {
            ((ITestAnnotation) annotation).setInvocationCount(5);
        }
    }

 }

}
```

Added new xml file with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Smoke Tests Suite">
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.common.MyTransformer">
    </listener>
</listeners>
<test name="Smoke Tests">
    <classes>
        <class name="FullyLoadTrain.JourneySearch1PaxTest"></class>

        </classes>
 </test>
```

And ran as testng Suite.

The test method CreateBookings() ran 5 times as expected as this number was mentioned in the invocationCount in the Transformer Class. However I need this number to come in as a variable passed from the test class. Is there a way we can achieve this?